# Searching previous command history with PageUp in 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, search

I got this working before (I believe it was on a 15.10, I recently downgraded to the LTS 14.04).

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74631/how-do-i-search-my-command-line-history-for-commands-i-used-before) the following should work

```
~ $ cat ~/.inputrc 
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

But when I save that `.inputrc` and open a new terminal, typing PageUp or PageDown just prints the tilde character `~` in the terminal, instead of doing the search.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

Try this in `~/.inputrc`

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward   
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

and reopen terminal.

Answer (score 10):

`\e[A` and `\e[B` are actually the Up and Down arrow keys. To test what a key is, run `cat` and then press the key:

```
$ cat
^[[A
^[[B

^[[5~
^[[6~
```

Those are <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> respectively. The `^[` stands for <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or `\e` in terms of `.inputrc`.

So, if you added `\e[A` and `\e[B`, you should be able to browse history using arrow keys. For <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, use `\e[5~` and `\e[6~`.

Comment: Wow! I have so often see these escape sequences in the terminal, wondering what they were. Even though I already use them in eg.  .inputrc, I have never made the connection. Very useful tip, thanks.

Comment: Upvoting as the answer provides an explanation of what is happening. Brilliant. For those looking at where to find the inputrc file, you can also look for it in the path /etc/