# terminal - Save chmod executable (./) as terminal command

Tags: command-line

How can i save a `./` executable as a terminal command? Like, so I don't longer have to type `./` in order to run the executable.

Comment: Make an alias that runs `./command` ?

Comment: @SorenA Yup, that's what I mean.

Comment: Why type in the same command over and over again when you can do a [history search](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74631/how-do-i-search-my-command-line-history-for-commands-i-used-before)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the application you would like to start is located at `/some/path` and you are trying to start a program called `executable`, please change accordingly

1. add `/some/path` to your `$PATH` variable.

   - You can do this temporarily by typing `export PATH=$PATH:/some/path`
   - To do this permanently, but only for the current user add the above command to the end of `~/.profile`
   - To achieve this globally open the `/etc/environment` file and make the end of the `PATH="` line read `:/some/path"`
2. link your executable to a path that is already on the `PATH` variable (`echo $PATH`) e.g. `ln -s /some/path/executable ~/bin`