# Ubuntu 22.04 automatic suggestion of past commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, 22.04

I am new to Ubuntu. On Windows, for the command line, I have been using this great little CLI tool called Clink, which (https://mridgers.github.io/clink/), which remembers past commands and also suggests commands based on the commands available from your path. When writing a line, it shows in transparent letters the statement that you possibly want to write, and you can simply hit right arrow to complete it. This saves a lot of time. On Ubuntu, I just found the tab-completion (but without transparent suggestions) and of course hitting arrow up to scroll through past commands. But I am sure there must be something like clink installable for ubuntu, as well, right? What are your suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When on the command line enter
ctrl+R
then start typing your command and it will autocomplete using your command history.
See more details [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44997/how-to-use-bash-history-to-improve-your-command-line-productivity/#:%7E:text=The%20bash%20shell%20stores%20the,bash_history.):

Answer (score 1):

There is the "build-in" [history search](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74631/how-do-i-search-my-command-line-history-for-commands-i-used-before) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, start typing part of the previous command, and it will search matches.

Fuzzy finder, `fzf`, provides such functionality, but on steroids. Type something, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and a list of matching commands will immediately be displayed, which you can select and execute when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Install fuzzy finder with the command `sudo apt install fzf` and add the line

```
source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/key-bindings.bash
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file to enable integration with `fzf`.

To be complete here, you can also add

```
source /usr/share/doc/fzf/examples/completion.bash
```

to have a command autocomplete feature provided by `fzf`.