# Common admin commands?

Tags: command-line, permissions, administration

I usually work with administrator access privileges on my Ubuntu workstations. On a new machine, I've recently been offered only a normal user account; and asked to provide a list of admin-level commands which I would like to use.

As such requests take a long time, I would like to get this right first-time. Is there a command which can analyse my command-line history, and report on which would normally have required admin access? Currently, I can only think of `apt-get`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I search my command-line history for commands I used before?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74631/how-do-i-search-my-command-line-history-for-commands-i-used-before)

Comment: Yes and no. While it weakens the question to say so, I'd honestly forgotten that I always type `sudo` at the start of each admin command. That is, I wouldn't have found the question you refer to, because I thought there was no such text to grep. (Perhaps it would be a better question from a user who does use the root account.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use root, but a regular user with sudo privilidges, you can run

```
history | grep sudo
```

Comment: Thanks. I had completely forgotten that I type `sudo` before all such commands :-)